# select block date option in react dates component

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-dates component in my app. I wants to block some days to show holiday in calendar and the holidays are showing in calendar but i am not able to select it. is there any option we can select the block date in react-dates component.

this is my component
`

```
<SingleDatePicker
 date={startDate}
 weekDayFormat="ddd"
 initialVisibleMonth={() => moment(initialValues)}
 onNextMonthClick={this.nextMonthClick}
 onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
 onFocusChange={(focusedInput) =>  onFocusChange(focusedInput)}
 isDayHighlighted={day1 => this.returnDates().some(day2 => isSameDay(day1, day2))}
isDayBlocked={day1 => this.returnDates().some(day2 => isSameDay(day1, day2))}
/>
```

`

this is my function to highlight and block dates

```
returnDates = () =>{
    const { filteredList } = this.props;
    let calendarEventDates = [];
        filteredList && filteredList.eventDates && filteredList.eventDates.length > 0  && filteredList.events.map(event => {
            let eventDate = moment(event.startDate);
            if(!event.isHoliday){ calendarEventDates.push(eventDate); }
            else{ calendarEventDates.push(eventDate); }
        });
        return calendarEventDates;
}
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: seems to be working, can you create demo in stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes it is working. the issue is I am not able to select blocked date(It is disabled by default).I wants to show a holiday card by selecting that blocked date but because of its default behaviour i can't able to do it. do you have any idea?

Comment: So, you want to show date disabled, but user can still choose it?

Comment: yeah right! If we can do any customisation on it?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `renderDayContents` to modify its contents,

and assign function to it

```
renderDayContents={renderDay}
```

And return the style you want to apply from it.

```
renderDay(day) {
    const holidayColor = this.getHolidayColor(day);

    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: holidayColor ? holidayColor : 'white', height: '100%', color: 'black' }}>
        <span>{day.format('D')}</span>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the related [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/374)